# Showing a set is linearly independent on infinite vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

For a finite dimensional vector space $V$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$, we get the following result:

Let $\beta$ be a basis for $V$. Then $\beta$ is a basis for $V$ if and only if each $v\in V$ can be uniquely expressed as a linear combination of vectors in $\beta$.

The proof of this is straightforward, however; in the infinite dimensional case we state the following:

Let $\beta$ be a subset of an infinite dimensional vector space $V$. Then $\beta$ is a basis for $V$ if and only if for each non zero vector $v\in V$, there exists unique vectors $u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_n\in\beta$ and unique non zero scalars $c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_n\in\mathbb{F}$ such that $v=c_1u_1+c_2u_2+\cdots+c_nu_n$.

Attempted proof:

If $\beta$ is a basis, then span$(\beta)$=V, so it suffies to show  that for every $v\in V$, its linear representation is unique, but this follows from the fact that $\beta$ is linearly independent.

The converse is where I have a problem, evidently span$(\beta)$=V, but showing that $\beta$ is linearly independent is quite troublesome. For the finite dimensional case we use the fact that the zero vector has a unique representation as a linear combination of elements in $\beta$, but here we dont have such hypothesis. What could follow?

Comment: You still have the hypothesis. If there were a non-trivial way to write $0$ as a linear combination of basis vectors, then you could construct a non-zero vector with two different ways to write it as a linear combination.

Comment: Suppose an equation $\sum c_iu_i=0$ possessed a non-trivial solution. If $v=\sum b_iu_i\ne 0$ for some $b_i$ then $v=\sum (b_i+c_i)u_i$, a contradiction.